# Filtering Records on the basis of complex queryParams

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I need to perform complex filtering depending upon the query params.

[Using SelectableEntityFiltering in Jersey 2.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013354/using-selectableentityfiltering-in-jersey-2-17/30016758#30016758)

This post and every where i can only find filtering for the select operation.
what if i need to do more complex fetching like

api/employees?query=empId>10 AND empId<20 AND firstName LIKE "abc*"

This kind of feature is possible in ADF REST Framework

[Filtering a Resource Collection with a Query Parameter with ADF REST Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/adf/develop/GUID-589F3905-5A8D-402D-B2D2-3BEEB2D7DDD4.htm#ADFFD54129)

I need to know if this kind of approach is possible via Jersey.

A million thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can pass parameters that later you use to build a query against the database: api/employees?minEmpId=10&maxEmpId=20&firstNameBeginsWith=abc

Comment: Thanks @Danilo
But i think using this will lead me to write queryParams for every attributes and they may make the code harder to maintain coz i will have to take care of so many scenarios..